# In Eclipse 3.5 (and with the Aptana plugins), how do I get a view that I can use to show my project, including "dot" files?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, dotfiles

I've managed to get the various project explorer views to show dot files, such as .htaccess, but if I ever close the project and reopen it, the dot files no longer show up in the view. Am I missing a view that lets me show the dot files or is there some kind of configuration option that I can toggle? I've tried a few things over the past few days, but I'm not sure what they were, since I really didn't keep track.

Suggestions?

Comment: Just added the line where filter settings is saved. Could you check if that could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've managed to get the various project explorer views to show dot files:

[alt text http://www.gentleware.com/fileadmin/media/archives/userguides/apolloforeclipse_userguide/images/filter.png](http://www.gentleware.com/fileadmin/media/archives/userguides/apolloforeclipse_userguide/images/filter.png)

That is normally done through the [filter view of a Package Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-java-element-filters.htm), by deactivating the 'resources' filter (`.*`).
That is normally saved into the ui preference file:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
```

Can you check that this file is properly updated when you change its settings?

I confirm those settings are in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` file, under the line:

```
CustomFiltersActionGroup.org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer.userDefinedPatterns=*.contrib, *.bak, *.launch, *.zip, *.rar, *.pmd, *.log
```

(those are example values for a filter)

However: while eclipse is running, adding a filter does not trigger any setting file modification. The new filter is strictly in memory during the eclipse session.
Only at the end of the session, during the eclipse closing step, you can find this filter written in `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs`.

In my case, closing/reopening a project did re-use correctly those global filters in the Package Explorer.
Could you check if this line is present in `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs`, and if not, add it (restart eclipse) and see if this now works as expected?

Comment: Do you know what property contains this data? Also, there's a UI prefs file for Aptana, so if the view is an Aptana view, could the property be there? I looked in both and didn't see anything that stood out.

Comment: @Thomas: I thought they were in org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs, but that turn out not to be the case. I will investigate a bit more and see if I can find those settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Navigator View, which will show the dot files by default.

[Navigator View http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/1116/screen2w.png](http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/1116/screen2w.png)

Comment: My navigator does not show dot files by default, but I was able to make it show them. However, when I close the project, they are once again now shown.